Cannot connect to Azure Event Hub
I am trying to use azure-sdk-for-cpp to connect to Azure Event Hub. But it is not working, I get error "Could not open Claims Based Security object."
I am following samples in the sources.
I have just this simple code and exception is thrown in GetEventHubProperties:
Azure::Messaging::EventHubs::ProducerClient producerClient(connectionString, eventhubName);
Azure::Messaging::EventHubs::Models::EventHubProperties eventhubProperties = producerClient.GetEventHubProperties();

In Azure Portal I have created resource group with Event Hubs Namespace. In it I have Event Hub called "tolp-985-event-hub" which I am using as eventhubName. I was trying various things as connectionString: From Event Hubs Namespace - Settings - Shared Access Policies - RootManageSharedAccessKey - Connection string–primary key. I tried also from Event Hub itself - Settings - Shared Access Policies - it was empty, I created a new policy with Manage+Send+Listen and from there Connection string–primary key. I tried without "EntityPath" in the connection string. I tried with it and with empty eventhubName, I tried various combinations but none working. I am probably missing some simple configuration or something...
To test if this is no fundamental problem with my environment etc. I tried something different from samples, to create a blob container with some content such as:
auto containerClient = Azure::Storage::Blobs::BlobContainerClient::CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, containerName);
containerClient.CreateIfNotExists();
for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    Azure::Storage::Blobs::BlockBlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlockBlobClient(blobName + std::to_string(j));
    blobClient.UploadFrom(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(blobContent.data()), blobContent.size());
}

There I use connection string from Storage Account and it works fine.
But connection string from Storage Account starts with "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" and maybe it is something very different from connection string for Event Hub, which starts with "Endpoint=sb://tolp-985-event-hubs-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=".
Thanks for any hint to get over this initial problem.
EDIT, code and images:
try {
    string connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://tolp-985-event-hubs-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=tolp-985-policy;SharedAccessKey=GGQyg...;EntityPath=tolp-985-event-hub";
    string eventhubName = "tolp-985-event-hub";
    Azure::Messaging::EventHubs::ProducerClient producerClient(connectionString, eventhubName);
    Azure::Messaging::EventHubs::Models::EventHubProperties eventhubProperties = producerClient.GetEventHubProperties();
} catch (std::exception &e) {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}

Event Hubs Namespace with Event Hub in it:

SAS Policy in the Event Hub:


The issue is with the connection to your Azure Event Hub, often related to the connection string or permissions. Check the Shared Access Policy has Manage, Send, and Listen permissions.

EventHub and Storage connection string formate is different.

As stated, I tried connection strings both for Event Hub Namespace (there was already SAS Policy: RootManageSharedAccessKey) and for Event Hub itself in the namespace (there was no policy, I created new SAS Policy: test-985-policy). For both policies I have Manage checked, which automatically checks also Send and Listen. I copied "Connection string–primary key" (not just "Primary key") from each of them, none worked for some reason.

The code is really just those two lines quoted above. Creating ProducerClient with connectionString and calling GetEventHubProperties on it. connectionString is what I wrote I tried. eventhubName is the name of the event hub (I tried just the name, tried also with namespace prefix). It throws mentioned exception. I can provide any more details of course, but it seems so simple. Test code is from samples, so probably portal side of configuration is wrong, I have no idea. I build it on Ubuntu, I used vcpkg to get sdk and it is working with blob container sample, but I need event hub...

The approach was correct. Configuration of Azure Portal was proper as verified by Python script doing the same operations. Connection string was used properly.
There was also no problem in the code itself built using Azure SDK for cpp.
Problem was in refused certificates. Although it worked from Python script and from C++ with BlobStorage, connection was refused from C++ with EventHub. Problem was in environment configuration related to Certificate Authority, SSL_CERT_FILE had to be set properly. Could be set in environment or in the code itself like
setenv("SSL_CERT_FILE", "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt", 1);

The test was done in Ubuntu.
To pinpoint the problem, detailed logs were activated by:
Azure::Core::Diagnostics::Logger::SetLevel(Azure::Core::Diagnostics::Logger::Level::Verbose);
Azure::Core::Diagnostics::Logger::SetListener([](Azure::Core::Diagnostics::Logger::Level, std::string const& message) {
    std::cout << "LOG: " << message << std::endl;
});


I have tried the sample code in my environment, it worked fine for me to send the messages to the Azure Event Hub.

Make sure to use the Event Hubs Namespace > Event Hub > Shared Access Policies > connection string with proper Manage, Send, and Listen permissions.

The Azure Event Hub connection string must be in the below format,
Endpoint=sb://<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=<poli-name>;SharedAccessKey=<key>;EntityPath=<eventhub-name>

main.cpp :
#include <azure/messaging/eventhubs.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 

int main()
{
  const char* eventhubConnectionString = std::getenv("EVENTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING");
  const char* eventhubName = std::getenv("EVENTHUB_NAME");

  if (eventhubConnectionString == nullptr)
  {
    std::cerr << "Missing environment variable EVENTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING" << std::endl;
    return 1;  
  }
  if (eventhubName == nullptr)
  {
    std::cerr << "Missing environment variable EVENTHUB_NAME" << std::endl;
    return 1; 
  }

  try
  {
    Azure::Messaging::EventHubs::ProducerClient producerClient(eventhubConnectionString, eventhubName);
    Azure::Messaging::EventHubs::Models::EventHubProperties eventhubProperties = producerClient.GetEventHubProperties();
    Azure::Messaging::EventHubs::EventDataBatchOptions batchOptions;
    batchOptions.PartitionId = eventhubProperties.PartitionIds[0];
    Azure::Messaging::EventHubs::EventDataBatch batch(producerClient.CreateBatch(batchOptions));
    {
      Azure::Messaging::EventHubs::Models::EventData event;
      event.Body = {1, 3, 5, 7};
      event.MessageId = "test-message-id-1";
      if (!batch.TryAdd(event))
      {
        std::cerr << "Failed to add the event to the batch (Event 1)" << std::endl;
        return 1;
      }
    }
    {
      Azure::Messaging::EventHubs::Models::EventData event;
      event.Body = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
      event.MessageId = "test-message-id-2";
      if (!batch.TryAdd(event))
      {
        std::cerr << "Failed to add the event to the batch (Event 2)" << std::endl;
        return 1;
      }
    }
    {
      Azure::Messaging::EventHubs::Models::EventData event{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8};  
      event.MessageId = "test-message-id-fibonacci";
      if (!batch.TryAdd(event))
      {
        std::cerr << "Failed to add the event to the batch (Fibonacci)" << std::endl;
        return 1;
      }
    }
    {
      Azure::Messaging::EventHubs::Models::EventData event{"Hello Eventhubs!"};
      event.MessageId = "test-message-id-helloworld";
      if (!batch.TryAdd(event))
      {
        std::cerr << "Failed to add the event to the batch (Hello Eventhubs)" << std::endl;
        return 1;
      }
    }

    producerClient.Send(batch);
    std::cout << "Events successfully sent to Event Hub!" << std::endl;
  }
  catch (const std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "An error occurred: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1; 
  }
  return 0; 
}

CMakeLists.txt :
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(MyAzureEventHubsProject)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "C:/Users/kamali/Documents/xxxxxx/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" CACHE STRING "Toolchain file for vcpkg")

find_package(azure-messaging-eventhubs-cpp CONFIG REQUIRED)
add_executable(main main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Azure::azure-messaging-eventhubs)

Output :
I ran the below command to set the Azure EventHub connection string and Event Hub Name in the env varaibles.
set EVENTHUB_CONNECTION_STRING="<EventHubConneString>"
set EVENTHUB_NAME="<HubName>"


The following code ran successfully and sent the messages to the Azure Event Hub as shown below.

Azure Event Hub :


Thank you very much for your help. I am checking it and I do not see any difference (beside things like reading value from environment rather than hardcoding it, etc. - I am just trying the very first step all the time). I updated my question with the code I am running and which throws the mentioned exception. I also added screenshots of my environment to see exactly the policy names, namespace and event hub... It seems to me exactly the same as you are doing it but there is probably something done wrongly...

@MartinD I will check and let you know.

Thanks for help. I went once again through configuration and the code and I really do not see the difference and reason. Not sure what I am missing, as it seems very simple.

@MartinD Check this sample from MS DOC to send messages to Azure Event Hub in c++.
If possible share your project structure image or GitHub repository.

Hi, that is C code. I can try it, but I need to make it work with cpp sdk. For now I just tried python code from the same page as a quick test. And that works fine. Events are sent and visible in Data Explorer in Portal. So connectionString and eventHub name I provide are not a problem, my Azure Portal side of configuration should be fine. It is something with libraries I use or environment, hard to say at the moment, I will try to find out somehow.

@MartinD Can you share your GitHub repository?

I have exactly the same code as you (except CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE of course). But not in Windows but in Ubuntu. As I now know it is not configuration as it works in Python, I think it is something in dependencies. I enabled logging by Diagnostics::Logger::SetLevel and Diagnostics::Logger::SetListener and I see SSL related errors like "Func: send_handshake_bytes: error:0A000086:SSL routines::certificate verify failed" or "Func: tlsio_openssl_send: Invalid tlsio_state. Expected state is TLSIO_STATE_OPEN." I need now to investigate this deeper - openssl in vcpkg, cerficates, etc.

Oh it is working now. Thanks so much for your help. It was indeed ssl configuration... I was missing environment variable SSL_CERT_FILE set to /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt so the connection was refused because of missing authority bundle. I was looking wrong way all the time... :-)

@MartinD I'm glad to know the issue is resolved.
